# In rsync, can I add exceptions to --delete using an external file?

Tags: rsync

I want `rsync` to:

- Copy all files from source to destination
- If a file does not exist anymore in the source, delete it from the destination, EXCEPT for some specific files

And I  need to list the exceptions **in a separate file**, like I can do with the `--exclude-from` option.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can have a file list in exclude option but you can try this:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude delete_file_1.php --exclude dir_1/file4.txt \
     directory_source/ directory_destination/
```

or you can:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude 'dir_1/dir_2/file_3.php' source/ destination/
```

or you can:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude 'dir*' <-- wildcard match here
```

If I were you I'd create test folders to be synced to remote destination and see how it works out. As long as you have the exclude option correct you can manipulate it to exclude plenty of files.

Comment: If I understand correctly this will not sync the files passed to `--exclude`. I need it to always sync all the files, and delete files that were removed from the source, except if the file is specified in a list. In other words, always sync everything, but never delete some specific files from destination. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is only possible if we run rsync 2 times, like this:

```
rsync -a source/ dest
rsync -a --exclude-from=files.txt --delete source/ dest
```

Where `files.txt` contains the files we don't want to delete.